# In Java streams, convert comma separated list of string into a List, but remove a substring at front of each string if present

Tags: java, string, java-stream

With Java streams, I am able to convert a comma separated list of `String`s into a `List`, but I also need to remove a substring at front of each string if present. How can I do this in streams?

What I have so far:

```
String source = "TF03,TF05,TF06,SQ07";
List<String> sourceList = Stream.of(source.split(",", -1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now I need to remove the "TF" or "SQ" or other prefixes in each string.

I need to edit the original question:

I need to remove "TF" or "SQ" or other prefixes but this prefix may also come in the form of a string.

```
 String substringToRemove = "TF"; 
 String source = "TF03,TF05,TF06,SQ07";
 List<String> sourceList = Stream.of(source.split(",", -1))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) with [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

```
String source = "TF03,TF05,TF06,SQ07";
List<String> sourceList = Stream.of(source.split(",", -1))
    .map(str -> str.replaceAll("^TF|SQ", ""))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```